# javamail does not send message content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email from a webapp using javamail and the email is sent without the body and attachment. I have tried debuging it and I can't see what is wrong.
I'm using tomee+ 1.7 and javamail 1.4.7.

Here is my code:

```
    // Msg body
        session.setDebug(true);
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("Attached are your query results");
        messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=windows-1255");
        messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");

        // attachment
        LOG.info("Building attachment from file " + file.getName());
        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachmentPart.attachFile(file);
        attachmentPart.setFileName(file.getName());

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

        // Send message
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Query report...");          
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        LOG.info("Sent message successfully ...");
```

The message I am getting:

```
From: x@x.x
To: x@x.x
Message-ID: <371010179.1.1409738093141.JavaMail.root@claimqa01>
Subject: Query report...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_1099874708.1409738093124"
```

Comment: "I have tried debuging it and I can't see what is wrong"; you could post the debugging output of javamail since you set `session.setDebug(true);`

Comment: Do you see an error message anywhere?

Comment: No error message anywhere.. I actually get an empty message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I removed the text part of the message and loaded the file content as String:

```
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(csv.getBytes("8859_8"),
                "text/csv")));
        message.setFileName("data.csv");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Query report...");
        Transport.send(message);
        LOG.info("Sent message successfully ...");
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to raise the old topic, but I hope it will help somebody.

The problem is that you have more than 1 java.mail jar in your classpath.
For example, I had something called geronimo javamail 1.4 jar in TomEE lib folder, that has the java mail's classes. You may think that you use the newest version of java.mail, but it is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Add messageBodyPart to the multipart before AttachmentPart.

If it still doesn't work, post the debug output.

You can examine the message that would be sent by adding message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); right before the Transport.send.

Also, you might want to upgrade to the [latest version of JavaMail - 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: tried both - doesn't help.. I edit the question to include the message content

Comment: Can you post the entire debug output?  I'm not convinced you're using the version of JavaMail you think you're using.  As another experiment, add message.saveChanges(); before the Transport.send.  If that fixes it, you're using a **very** old version of JavaMail.  Also, try wrapping your code in a try/catch to make sure you're not getting any unexpected exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exact root cause without error message you are getting. I have below code which works for me

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendFileEmail
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{

  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "web@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Create the message part 
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

     // Fill the message
     messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

     // Create a multipar message
     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

     // Set text message part
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Part two is attachment
     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     String filename = "file.txt";
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

     // Send the complete message parts
     message.setContent(multipart );

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: He wants to send an attachment, not just a text message. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks, I have updated my solution which supports email attachment